Is there a way to build a url that produces a specific search?
I have a Google Sheet which is populated by a Salesforce report of Cases. My desire is to build hyperlinks from this Google Sheet that take the user back to the individual Case. The most obvious answer would be to use a formula to build links directly to the Case using HYPERLINK(), but I can't see how to extract the needed ID as part of a report: in the instance of https://acme.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Case/400Pr00000DKVmcIAH/view, 400Pr00000DKVmcIAH doesn't seem to be readily accessible in a report.
What I do have access to is the Case ID (looks like 03776984). Is there a way to build a URL that searches for this case number, and maybe even refines the search with additional fields?

Not sure if you're just trying to obfuscate the ID value, or maybe a typo, but the 400 prefix is for ApexClass, not Case. The ID value for a case starts with 500. You don't necessarily need the entire URL, either; it is sufficient to use https://my-domain.lightning.force.com/500Pr00000DKVmcIAH, which Salesforce will automatically redirect to the Case view page. Case ID should be a standard field that you can include in any report that references cases.

I was, clearly aimlessly! Thank you -- I've spent more time on it and realised my error. Case number wasn't what I needed, it was instead Case ID, which I can easily build a standard url from, and can access through standard reporting.
